# colorScale property works for VictoryPie but not VictoryLegend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I'm displaying a pie chart using `VictoryPie`. Since the labels all overlap weirdly, I'd like to just use a VictoryLegend. I found this example `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/boygirl/1Lu96jq0/

The jsfiddle example specifies colors inside `colorScale`, like so: `colorScale={["tomato", "orange", "gold"]}`

However, my pie chart is dynamic and depends on user input so I can't predict how many colors I'll need. I tried `colorScale="blue"` inside VictoryLegend like I do in VictoryPieThe pie chart is correct, but all the legend labels are black. As an aside, the labels in my implementation also don't display vertically stacked like they do in the example, but rather expand across the page horizontally.

My render looks like this:

```
render() {
      const {
          data,
          pieChartData,
          beyondBudget,
          showResults,
          total,
          pieLegend
      } = this.state;
      const questions = data.questions;
      return (
          <div>
              {questions.map((q, i) => (
                  <UL key={i}>
                      <li>
                          <h4>{q.text}</h4>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <Options
                              state={this.state}
                              q={q}
                              i={i}
                              handler={this.handleInputChange}
                          />
                      </li>
                  </UL>
              ))}
              <button onClick={this.computeTotals}>Click</button>

              {console.log("trying the keys approach", this.state.pieLegend)}
                {this.state.showResults &&
                  (<div>
                    <VictoryLegend
                      standalone={false}
                        colorScale="blue"
                        legendWidth={50}
                        title="Legend"
                        centerTitle
                        style={{ border: { stroke: "black" } }}
                        data= {this.state.pieLegend}
                    />
                        <VictoryPie
                            colorScale="blue"
                            data={pieChartData}
                            labels={d => `${d.x}: ${d.y}%`}
                            style={{ parent: { maxWidth: '50%' } }}
                        />

                        {Object.keys(beyondBudget).length > 0 && (
                            <div>
                                <Table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Out of Budget</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <BrokeBudget
                                            beyondBudget={beyondBudget}
                                        />
                                    </tbody>
                                </Table>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                  )
                }
          </div>
      );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs:

> https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-legend/#colorscale
>
> colorScale type: array[string]
>   The colorScale prop defines a color scale to be applied to each data
>   symbol in VictoryLegend. This prop should be given as an array of CSS
>   colors, or as a string corresponding to one of the built in color
>   scales: "grayscale", "qualitative", "heatmap", "warm", "cool", "red",
>   "green", "blue". VictoryLegend will assign a color to each symbol by
>   index, unless they are explicitly specified in the data object. Colors
>   will repeat when there are more symbols than colors in the provided
>   colorScale.

`colorScale` is expecting an array of strings instead of a string, which is a type mistmatch and possibly in the VictoryLegend component its handling that as an error or ignoring it and rendering default instead thus the default color legends.

Change that to:

```
               <VictoryLegend
                    standalone={false}
                    colorScale={["blue"]}
                    legendWidth={50}
                    title="Legend"
                    centerTitle
                    style={{ border: { stroke: "black" } }}
                    data= {this.state.pieLegend}
                />
```

For orientation of legends use this prop: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-legend#orientation

Comment: `Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`